# How to use range() with string as integer to get data of string in python

Tags: python

I have data of string like this:

```
my_data = [
    "0100052253719270",
    "0100052253719271",
    "0100052253719272",
    "0100052253719273",
    "0100052253719274",
    "0100052253719275",
    "0100052253719276",
    "0100052253719277",
    "0100052253719278",
    "0100052253719279",
    "0100052253719280",
    "0100052253719281",
    "0100052253719282"
]
```

I would like to filter my_data base on `from_string` and `to_string` and return it into range of `my_data`.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: `element in range(int(from_string), int(to_string))`

Comment: VERY unclear what you actually want. Please clarify. what is `from_string` and what is `to_string`? what do you mean by "filter" my_data? what do you mean by "return it into range of my_data"? please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72195060/edit) your question to make it clear what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it:
`my_filterd_data = [ele for ele in my_data if int(ele) in range(int(from_string), int(to_string))]`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to create the list you have in the question. So try this,

```
["01000" + str(i) for i in range(52253719270, 52253719283)]
```